# Can't inject `Route` nor `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` into `HttpInterceptor`

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-dependency-injection

Simplified version of the code:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private readonly router: Router,
    private readonly activatedRouteSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    @Inject(AuthServiceFactory) private readonly authServiceFactory: ServiceFactoryBase<IAuthService>,
    @Inject(LoggingServiceFactory) private readonly loggingServiceFactory: ServiceFactoryBase<ILoggingService>) {
    console.log('router', router);
    console.log('activated-route-snapshot', activatedRouteSnapshot);
  }
```

None of that can be resolved. It fails with a standard message saying following:

> StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS ->
>   ActivatedRouteSnapshot]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform:
>   core)[InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS -> ActivatedRouteSnapshot]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRouteSnapshot!

..what is the correct way to import `RouterModule` into an application?

P.S. I got `SharedModule` rather than the `AppModule` to export all **mine** stuff but not Angular's:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: any.concat(pipes),
    providers: any
        .concat(serviceFactories)
        .concat(guards)
        .concat(otherProviders)
        .concat([{
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: JwtInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }]),
    exports: any.concat(pipes)
})
export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: any
                .concat(serviceFactories)
                .concat(guards)
                .concat(otherProviders)
        };
    }
}
```

The the `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: appComponents.concat(auxComponents),
  imports: [
    // theirs
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

    // ours
    SharedModule,
    CoursesModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Have you tried `RouterModule` in the import list for AppModule?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, yeap. Somewhy does not work: `Router` is not resolved, however it works with guards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using a `ClassProvider` as you must do for an `HttpInterceptor`, Angular can't compile provider dependencies like it would for providers that are included in the module as tokens themselves. Basically, type tokens don't really exist at runtime, and Angular uses these tokens for dependency injection -- since a `ClassProvider` or a `ValueProvider` are evaluated at runtime, they don't get the proper DI treatment they deserve.

You'll just have to be a bit more declarative about it:

```
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: JwtInterceptor,
        deps: [Router, ActivatedRoute],
        multi: true
    }
```

The tokens in the `deps` array will be injected into the component on creation. One finicky thing here is that the `deps` have to be in the same *order* as they are in the constructor parameters.

Also, an `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`'s provider is just `ActivatedRoute`.

You should be able to accomplish the same thing by using the `@Inject()` decorator, as you've done with the other providers -- Angular will walk up the dependency tree for the first match and inject it (though I'm not 100% certain on this).

Comment: It still expects appropriate declaration: `ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS -> ActivatedRouteSnapshot]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS -> ActivatedRouteSnapshot]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRouteSnapshot!`.

Comment: Oh, whoops. The provider for an `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` is actually just called `ActivatedRoute`.

Comment: Seems like something else there: `Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRoute: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`. It fails to include those guys to the `SharedModule` I guess.

Comment: In that case, I was wrong - take it out of `deps` and don't `@Inject` it. It's already a provider as part of the `RouterModule`, so it should be registered as a provider -- it wasn't meant to be re-registered in your own modules.

Comment: Ok, I fixed that one. Final solution is to do all you've mentioned (thanks) + just expect `Router` into contructor **not mentioning** it in the `providers` section. `Deps` are needed.

Comment: Yup. I got waaaay off track in my answer, sorry. I'll update it.

Comment: In my case i was using `RouterStateSnapshot`, for that also `ActivatedRoute` needs to be injected. Thanks